# Showing waypoint and its value in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am looking to place a railway within one of my QGIS maps. I would like to have a waypoint showing the location of each mile marker, but also show the value (mile marker number) above the waypoint.

How can I do this in QGIS?

I already have a *.csv* file with all the mile marker coordinates and a column with the corresponding mile marker value, but I can only get the map to show the waypoint location, not the value (mile marker number) of each waypoint as well.

Comment: Have a look at the [15.1.4. Labels Properties](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#labels-properties) to know how to show the labels of the waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ahmadhanb, the solution is to setting properly the labels of the waypoints.
Right click on the waypoint layer, than click on Properties and move to the Labels tab. Select Single labels from the menu and then in the Value box select the field in your layer that contains info about the mile marker value. In the section below you could also define as you prefer settings for label appearance.
[image]